# Expo 33 yarn workspaces - Callback with id 0: undefined.undefined() not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have this [project](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/fullstack-graphql-airbnb-clone), was created with the latest version of expo and typescript, (I chose it from the cli).

Everything works well, also I added it with the [expo-yarn-workspaces](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-yarn-workspaces) package, but I have this error when I try to scan the QR code with my android phone:

[image]

In `packages/app` you can find the react-native code...

I haven't added any logic to this app, it's only the default template that expo-cli creates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was a serious headache. Fortunately, I think I've got the fix for you.

Check the `node_modules` folder of your mobile application and ensure `expo` and `react-native` are both symlinked to the workspace-root's versions of these packages. In my case, the mobile application had a second copy of `react-native` rather than being symlinked, which was the cause of my trouble.

---

**Edit - More clarity:**

**TL:DR** If your `react-native` and `expo` folders inside of your mobile app's `node_modules` folder are not symlinked, delete them and rerun the `expo-yarn-workspaces postinstall` from the folder for your mobile app, NOT from the project root. These modules should only appear in the top level `node_modules` folder.

### Example Project structure

```
/MyRoot
  /node_modules
    /react-native
    /expo
  /packages
    /YourMobileApp
      /node_modules
        /react-native -- This should be a symlink to /MyRoot/node_modules/react-native
        /expo -- This should be a symlink to /MyRoot/node_modules/expo
    /SomePackage
    /SomeOtherPackage
```

### Example of what properly symlinked folders look like (Windows 7)

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all the work you put! You're awesome bro. But... Do you have any video or post where explains a little better what you're talking about 

Comment: @AndrésMontoya I updated my answer to hopefully be completely clear, but let me know if it's not. If this fixes your problem, don't forget to accept! Cheers!